# Eclipse Git commit shortcut key works in editor but not in navigator.

Tags: eclipse, git, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-pdt

Using Eclipse Indigo with PDT 3 on OSX 10.5 Leopard.

I have Customized Perspective and enabled the Git command group.

In the keys preferences I have tried a few different shortcuts, being sure to select ones that have no conflicts.

If I use my shortcut in a PHP editor, I get the git commit dialog. If I use the same keyboard shortcut when I'm in the PHP explorer view (with either a file or folder with changes selected), I get nothing. If I use either the toolbar button or menu command, I get the commit window.

If I re-assign the same shortcut for another git command (Add), it works when the PHP explorer has focus.

Is there something else I should be aware of, or trying? Why doesn't the keyboard shortcut for Git Commit work in PHP Explorer view?

Answer (score 0):

There still seems to be a pending issue on this [(apparently closed) bug 339838](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339838), even though that shortcut has no conflict.
You can check if this is related by checking your error log and comparing its content with the one detailed in that bug report.